# run flask app on ubuntu all the time

Tags: python, ubuntu, nginx, flask, ssh

I just coded a basic Flask app and run it by using `gunicorn`.

I can reach it by using the domain which points to my `nginx` webspace while I am connected via `ssh` with my `ubuntu vServer`.

How can I make it to stay online while I am not connected via `ssh`? Is there a way I can turn it on and off whenever I like to?

The point is everyone should be able to connect even when I am not currently connected in `ssh`.

Comment: Run it in background. `<insert gunicorn command> &` you can check job status by using `jobs` command.

Comment: [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/): A Process Control System. Google "Flask Supervisor" - lots of tutorials around.